# Salesforce Attachment data content type conversion issue

Tags: salesforce, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to fetch attachments (of any content type and any size) from Salesforce. After the attachment is queried using Salesforce Query, I save the attachment details (payload.Name, payload.Body and payload.ContentType) in a variable (as an array). Below is the email payload that I am constructing before the Outlook email send operation.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Binaries
output application/json
var subject =  "This is a test"
var attachments = vars.varAttachmentArray map ((item, index) -> {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    name: item.filename[0],
    contentType: item.contentType[0],
    contentBytes: toBase64(item.content[0] as Binary)
})
---
{
    "message": {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "HTML",
            "content": "Test"
        },
        "toRecipients": [{
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "test@myorg.com"
            }
        }],
        "ccRecipients": [],
        "attachments": attachments
    },
    "saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

It works fine with text files (text/plain). For other attachment types (like excel application/vnd.ms-excel), it sends the attachment, but while trying to open I get this:

> The file format and extension of 'Test.xls' don't match. The file
> could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open
> it. Do you want to open it anyway?

The data inside is messed up after opening, with all formatting and sheets lost. How can I make sure the formatting and original content is not lost while sending the attachments? The Body from Salesforce is of type Base64. Please advise.

Comment: Could you share minimal data to reproduce the issue? It will be hard to do with a binary file here though. What are the content types? Why are you using a JSON output?

Comment: If the attachment data that you retrieved from Salesforce is already in base64, shouln't you just map it and not covert it again to base64 (as per above snippet: contentBytes: toBase64(item.content[0] as Binary)?